# SqliteConnection Trace event refuses to fire

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I have used NUGET to install the Sqlite Core package into my c# project using:

```
>Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core
```

I create a database connection as follows:

```
var data = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
```

I then hook an event handler to the update event which fires every time that an update statement occurs (for the purposes of a last write date field for a particular piece of business logic)

```
data.Update += DataOnUpdate;
```

This is all awesome. However the SqliteConnection class also exposes an event called **Trace** The documentation says the following about this event:

```
"This event is raised whenever SQLite Statement First begins executing on this connection. It only applies for the given connection"
```

I read this to mean that it performs a similar function to the Update event whereby it should fire whenever an SQL statement is being executed.

**HOWEVER**

When I hook this event up as follows:

```
data.Trace += DataOnTrace;
```

It never fires. I have tried SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE TABLE, TRANSACTIONS and basically every bit of Sql logic that I can think of and it refuses to fire.

What is this event there for if not to fire? or is there something I need to do to get the connection to fire this event?

Answer (score 10):

I downloaded the System.Data.SQLite package and wrote the following code.  The trace event seems to fire OK for me.

Given a SQLite database containing a table called "tbl1" (schema unimportant)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\dev\Sandbox\Sandbox.Console\test.db;Version=3;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            conn.Trace += conn_Trace;

            using(SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from tbl1", conn))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);

                }
            }

            conn.Trace -= conn_Trace;
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    static void conn_Trace(object sender, TraceEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Statement);
    }
```

Comment: The key point is that you have to subscribe to the event _after_ calling Open

Comment: I would really encourage @TimRobinson comment be included in an updated answer as this was key to my issue.